# SQL Where Statement - Comparing to Instance Variable in C

Tags: sql, objective-c, xcode, sqlite, where-clause

Could anyone help me with the following WHERE statement ? I want to say "Where Name is equal to name".

```
NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT Name, Description, Postcode, AddressLine1, ImageURL, Cost FROM MainDetails WHERE Name=@%", name];
```

Thanks in advance,

Martin

Comment: Please keep in mind that this leaves you wide open to a SQL injection attack if you don't sanitize your inputs.

Comment: Sorry - new to SQL - what does this mean ?>

Comment: Another thought, you might want to look at using Core Data rather that having to write the SQL by hand. Go through a Code Data tutorial project and you should be up and running in a day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you're missing the single quotes.

NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT Name, Description, Postcode, AddressLine1, ImageURL, Cost FROM MainDetails WHERE Name='@%'", name];

Comment: Thanks but still not working. Do spaces matter in SQL e.g if name is "The Whitehouse" will it match against "The Whitehouse" in my table ?

Comment: Spaces do matter. When using the = operator, it must be an exact match, including the correct upper/lower case. Perhaps look at the LIKE operator instead. You can use wildcard characters and have it ignore case.

Answer (score 4):

String values need to be quotes in SQL. So you need something like:

```
NSString *query = [... "... Name='@%'", name];
```

(assuming the rest of the syntax is valid, I don't know Objective-C)